# Golang Docker MongoDB ec2 machine mongo connection error

Tags: docker, go, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I am trying to deploy an application with golang, mongoDB, docker-compose at AWS ec2 machine. I prepared my image and docker compose file and tried locally and everything is fine but, at ec2 machine i have a mongoDB connection error in same container network. My docker compose file is:

```
version: "3.5"
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    external: true
networks:
  mongo-go:
    external: true

services:
  api:
    image: repo/image:latest
    container_name: api01
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - mongo-go

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      - mongo-go
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/var/lib/mongo01
```

And my mongo connection code is :

```
func NewMongoClient(conn string) *mongo.Client {
   client, err := mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://mongodb:27017"))
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
   defer cancel()
   err = client.Connect(ctx)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   err = client.Ping(ctx, nil)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   return client
}
```

And I am getting panic like:

`panic: server selection error: context deadline exceeded, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: mongodb:27017, Type: Unknown }, ] }`

Where is my mistake? Thank you!

I tried to create docker network and communicate golang app with mongoDB. But it was not happened :/

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the way you define mongo-go network in your config file. It's defined external with true, docker-compose won't create this network. Check docker-compose [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#network-configuration-reference:%7E:text=with%2Dempty%2Dvalue%22-,external,-%F0%9F%94%97).

Change it to the following definition:

```
networks:
  mongo-go: {}
```